# How can I match the strings in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, match, substr

I got stuck on this.. Let's say, i have string1 & string 2 (in the same model), which string1 has 7 digits and string2's 2 digits.
then i want to match them together, where 2 of the string1's beginning digits must be same as the string2. I tried this code in model >>

```
public function CekDigit($attribute,$params)
{

$attribute=substr($this->string1,0,-7);
$params=$this->string2;

if($this->$attribute==$params['subject'])
{
$this->addError(‘Error’, $params['message']);
return false;
}
}
```

while in rules, i put this code >>

```
    <?php

array('string1','cekdigit','message'=>'the code is unmatched','subject'),

?>
```

After i made that code, i tried to fill $string1 with 23xxxxxxx
but  i got an error, which is CException : Property model.23 is not defined. Could anyone help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: can you print $_POST inside CekDigit() and copy paste the result.

Comment: i don't think you know what is going on there... please read this thoroughly - http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/

Comment: looks like your're calling `$string1` as `$$string1` at some stage.  Also, looks like you're setting `$params` to be a string (`$params=$this->string2`) but then you're trying to compare against an array value (`$params['subject']`)

Answer (score 0):

Using your example the line `$attribute=substr($this->string1,0,-7);`
will set $attribute to 23, So the line `if($this->$attribute==$params['subject'])`
will check `$params['subject']` against `$this->23`.

Try

```
public function CekDigit($attribute, $params)
{ 
    $string1 = substr($this->$attribute, 0, 2); 
    if ($string1 == $this->string2)
        {
        $this->addError(‘Error’, $params['message']);
        return false;
    }
}
```